# link with DB2 ODBC drivers on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, odbc, db2

I need to link our C/C++ code that is using the DB2 ODBC driver on linux, and although ive pulled in sqlcli.h I dont know where to find the objects so i can link.

Ive installed DB2 v9.1 ESE so i wouldve thought i could get everything.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application (on the *client*) would link to a Unix ODBC library -- either iODBC or unixodbc. Both are commonly available on Debian and Ubuntu and other distros.

Next, you install the ODBC driver from the *server database*.  This means you need to get a DB2 ODBC driver onto your system.

With that, your application is capable of 'talking ODBC' and has someone to talk to: the ODBC driver of DB2.

To give another concrete example, I compile RODBC again unixodbc-dev for Debian and can then talk via ODBC to MySQL and Postgresql as I have drivers for both. [ This is of course contrived as both MySQL and Postgresql have native drivers too, but it servers as a test of RODBC. ]

Comment: So the DB2 ODBC driver is on the server, and my client application just links with Unixodbc?

Comment: No, you need a DB2 ODBC driver for your operating system to be installed on your client machine.  That way you enable (on the client) a 'conversation' about ODBC that this DB2 driver can then link back to the server.

Comment: right. Cheers!. Im still having trouble connecting but i think i have it worked out.